# Not Complete Links Are Printed In Preview Using Abc Pdf

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, ckeditor, abcpdf

I Have Used A Ck Editor To Add Some Data in My Document. and I Added Some Links Into It Using Link Button At Ck Editor.But When I preview (ABC Pdf) , Links Are Shown Incomplete and A few Links Are broken i.e they do not work as Expected. it only happens with lengthy links.i manually Added a line break in a link and then it appeared fine and worked too.
What I am missing ?

Comment: It would be great if you can add your source code. Thanks

Comment: @SibeeshVenu its a lengthy code that is only converting html to pdf.   theDoc.AddImageHtml(content, true, 784, true);where Content Contains Html Of My Data in CkEditor. Moreover i have set this property too....theDoc.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After A Severe head Ache , Solved My Issue.
I Simply Edited My Ck Editor=>Plugin=>Dialog=>Link.js File And Added An Attribute In OnOk Function.

This Simply Solved My Problem.

> c.set["style"] = "Word-Wrap:Break-Word";

or you can simply edit your styling for that particular tag/attribute i.e

> Style ="Word-Wrap:Break-Word;"

I Hope It Will Help Out Someone In Future , Thanks!